# Change size of image in Quarto presentation

Tags: image, reveal.js, quarto

I would like to make the image smaller using `width` and `heigth`. But when I change this, the images place is complete different while specifying top right with `top` and `right`. Here is a reproducible example without change size:

```
---
title: "test"
format: revealjs
editor: visual
---

## Slide

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes:

-   Content authored with markdown
-   Output from executable code
-   Another point

![](R_logo.svg.png){.absolute top=0 right=0}
```

Output:

[image]

And with changing size:

```
---
title: "test"
format: revealjs
editor: visual
---

## Slide

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes:

-   Content authored with markdown
-   Output from executable code
-   Another point

![](R_logo.svg.png){.absolute top=0 right=0 width = "100" height = "100"}
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the image is now at the bottom which is not what I want. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying style using `key=val` inline, do not put space before and after the equal sign (`=`),

```
![](Rlogo_svg.png){.absolute top=0 right=0 width=100 height=100}
```

---

[image: output]

---

Comment: That was indeed the solution! I see that `width="100"` and `width=100` both work, good to know! Thanks again @shafee

Comment: @Quinten, However, since you are giving the class `absolute` to this image, defining rules for that class in a CSS file or css chunk seems a bit more safe option to me.